# LINQ: use anonymous type

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, anonymous-types

I'm sure that this is basic for someone that knows the answer. But I'm stuck. I've tried to look up the answer to no avail. How do I reference the fbRegistered value later in the code?

```
using (kvEntities ent = new kvEntities())
    {           
        var user = from u in ent.kvUsers
                   where u.fbID == id
                   select new { u.fbID, u.fbRegistered};

        if (user.fbRegistered)   // < ???
        {
            // so how do I reference fbRegistered just above? 
            // this gives me an error.
        }
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `user` contains collection. Use `First` or `Single` methods:

```
if (user.First().fbRegistered) ...
```

Comment: Bravo, thank you jimmy for the quick answer. Once I see this syntax, I know what to do now (easy peasy) ... I just didn't know (and couldn't find) the correct syntax ... thanks and Happy New Year ! ... ;-)